# How do I get mdfind to include folder matches in addition to files?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

In terminal I am using `mdfind 'kMDItemFSLabel = 6'` to find everything with a Red file label on my Mac. However, it seems to be excluding folders with a red label. I'm trying to get it turn also return folders but I can't seem to even get any of these folder-only queries to work let alone add it to the current file results. `mdfind kind:folders` and `mdfind 'kMDItemFSLabel=6'` work independently but I can't figure out how to get both:

```
mdfind kind:folders AND 'kMDItemFSLabel == 6'
mdfind 'kind:folders' AND 'kMDItemFSLabel == 6'
mdfind 'kind:folders kMDItemFSLabel == 6'
mdfind kind:folders kMDItemFSLabel == 6
etc
```

All I get is `Failed to create query for [query above]`

What is the correct syntax?

And once I get that right, how do I say "folders AND all files"? Something like `kind:folders+all'?

Edit: Also tried:

```
mdfind kind:folders && 'kMDItemFSLabel == 6'   returns every folder on my computer
mdfind kind:folders && kMDItemFSLabel == 6   returns every folder on my computer
mdfind 'kind:folders' && 'kMDItemFSLabel == 6' returns every folder on my computer
mdfind 'kind:folders && kMDItemFSLabel == 6'   failed to create query
```

Comment: If you use `mdls` on one of the folders you expect to match, does it show the label?

Comment: Just tried it and yes it does. `kMDItemFSLabel = 6`

Comment: Does the Spotlight GUI find the folders? If it does, try saving the search and then examining the query in the Get Info window or the file XML in a text editor.

Comment: All of the commands in which `&&` appeared outside of quotes were not what you thought. The `&&` was interpreted by the **shell** as though you had entered two separate commands, the second of which was only to execute if the first succeeded.

Comment: Searching "label:red" in a Finder spotlight works if that's what you mean by Spotlight GUI (the menubar one doesn't seem to take arguments like that). I saved a search for Red (which finds all the folders) and here is the Get Info for that .savedsearch http://i.imgur.com/DuN0jB0.png. Looking at it it looks like it's using the query "((_kMDItemFinderLabel = 6))".

Comment: It appears the underscore fixes it! This is what I typed into terminal `mdfind _kMDItemFinderLabel = 6`. I would like to understand _why_ this is, though, if you happen to know. Is this a standard convention with bash, underscore means include folders? Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that's it. Typically, a leading underscore means "private to Apple". Note that `...FinderLabel` is different from `...FSLabel`. I did a test and when I search for a label (which is now called a "tag") and saved it, the query was `kMDItemUserTags = "Purple"cd`. `mdls` listed `kMDItemUserTags` as an array, which makes sense since you can apply multiple tags to items. So, I suspect you should be searching on that.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't notice it was a different attribute name. It looks like both _kMDItemFinderLabel and kMDItemUserTags both give the same result but kMDItemUserTags is probably the better choice since Apple has moved to tags instead of labels. Now just for my knowledge, what is the correct way to combine this with 'kind:folders' if I wanted to limit this to folders (or only files)? I still can't get the above combinations to work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I was unable to mark an answer because everything was posted into the comments so all I could do was upvote Ken. The answer below was added after my last visit on this page but I will mark it now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**tl; dr**

Use the following, ***locale-independent* commands**:

- files *and* folders:

  - `mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags == Red'`
- files *only*:

  - `mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags == Red && ! kMDItemContentType == public.folder'`
- folders *only*:

  - `mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags == Red && kMDItemContentType == public.folder'`

***Simpler*, but *locale-specific* equivalents** - ***these examples only work in English-language locales*** and *must be localized to work with other locales*:

- files *and* folders:

  - `mdfind 'tag:red'`
- files *only*:

  - `mdfind 'tag:red AND NOT kind:folder'`
- folders *only*:

  - `mdfind 'tag:red AND kind:folder'`

For background information, read on.

---

As it turns out, **Spotlight - and therefore `mdfind` - speak two distinct languages**:

- **SL - Simple language**: A ***simplified, LOCALIZED* language** based on `<attribName>:<attribVal` pairs

  - based on **simplified, *localized* attribute names** comprising only a ***subset* of all attributes** (however, alternatively, you can *also* use the full, locale-independent attribute names)

    - some attribute *values* are localized as well; e.g., attribute `kind`(`kMDItemKind`) is explicitly designed to report a localized value
  - based on simplified matching rules
  - combined with Boolean operators `AND` (default), `OR`, and `NOT` (note that these do *not* get localized).
- **FL - Flexible language**: A **more powerful and locale-independent**, but **more complex and verbose language**

  - based on the **locale-independent underlying attribute names**
  - using a range of relational operators
  - with more flexible value-matching options
  - combined with Boolean operators `&&` (default), `||`, and `!`

<sup>If anyone knows what to *properly* call these two languages, please let me know.</sup>

**Caveat:** **These two languages cannot be mixed** - a given query string must use either one or the other syntax.

The solutions below are tagged with **SL** and **FL** accordingly.
Given that SL uses *localized* names, **I recommend using the SL solutions for predictable, locale-independent results, despite being more complex and verbose.**

---

To find all **files *and* folders** that are **tagged with the red label**, use:

- FL:

  ```
    mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags == Red'
  ```
- SL (English):

  ```
    mdfind 'tag:red' # in German, `tag:red` would be `attribut:red`
  ```

---

To find **files *only*** (as opposed to *folders*) that are tagged with the red file/folder label, use:

- FL:

  ```
    mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags == Red && ! kMDItemContentType == public.folder'
  ```
- SL (English):

  ```
    mdfind 'tag:red AND NOT kind:folder' # in German, `kind:folder` would be `art:ordner`
  ```

---

To find **folders *only*** (as opposed to *files*) that are tagged with the red file/folder label, use:

- FL:

  ```
    mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags == Red && kMDItemContentType == public.folder'
  ```
- SL (English):

  ```
    mdfind 'tag:red AND kind:folder'
  ```

---

General **tips for using `mdfind`**:

- **Pass the query as one, *single-quoted* string**, so as to protect it from interpretation by the *shell* (as above).
- If you're unsure how to formulate a query:

  - Create the desired query *interactively* via Finder's search field (start typing and select query fields from the pop-up list, or press `+` in the top-right corner for creating multiple, AND-combined criteria line by line with the assistance of pop-up lists)
  - save it to a `*.savedSearch` file (`Save` button in the top-right corner, which saves to `~/Library/Saved Searches/` by default),
  - and open an Inspector window for that file and look at the `Query:` field.
  - Note that such system-created queries always use the FL language.
- To see a **list of all supported metadata attributes** and their description, examine the output from `mdimport -A`.

  - Column 1 contains the FL attribute names.
  - Column 4 contains the SL attribute names (simplified, localized).
- To restrict matches to a specific folder's subtree, use the `-onlyin <folder>` option.
- To output the value of specific metadata attributes after the path of matches, use one or more `-attr <attribName>` options.

---

**Documentation**:

**Note: The documentation is woefully lacking and, in parts, incorrect.**<sup>as of 16 May 2015</sup>

- [About File Metadata Queries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001841)
- [Query expression syntax - FL ONLY](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001849-CJBEJBHH)

  - **Caveat:** the `c` and `d` options are explained as needing to be appended to the *operator* as `[c]` and `[d]`, as opposed to the (right-hand-side) *operand*, which is what OSX itself does when you save interactively constructed queries; also, at least on other option exits that's not even mentioned: `w`; if you append one or more option letters to a quoted string, their meaning is as follows
  - `c` ... match case-INsensitively
  - `d` ... ignore diacritics (marks above and below the base letter of foreign characters) when matching
  - `w` ... match as a whole word (from what I can tell)
  - You can also use the familiar `*` (any sequence of chars.) and `?` (one char.) wildcards.
- [List of *common* Metadata Attributes - FL ONLY](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001694-SW1)

  - Note that since Spotlight is extensible with plugins, any given machine may have additional attributes; to see the file-type-to-attributes mappings, run `mdimport -X` and look at the entries of the `Types` key.

---

**All in all, as of macOS 10.10.3, `mdfind` and the Spotlight query language are poorly documented, finicky beasts** - trial and error are often your best friends, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemContentType = "public.folder" && kMDItemUserTags = "Red"cd'
```

By the way, the `cd` on the end of `"Red"` means the match should ignore case (upper vs. lower) and diacritical marks (accents, etc.).