# filter out photos with different exif date on Mac

Tags: macos, exif, exiftool

I'm looking for a way on macOS to filter out photos which creation date doesn't match the exif photo date.
What is the best tool for doing this?

Comment: `exiftool` Use **homebrew** to install it `brew install exiftool`

Comment: You can probably do it with the built-in `mdfind` tool and a bit of `awk` too... https://stackoverflow.com/a/45900228/2836621

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try exiftool. Thank you very much

Comment: Very good. Thank you friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert with `exiftool` but think I have got something that is 90% of what you want. I am writing it up step-by-step so that:

- you can adapt it if it's not exactly what you meant, and
- so I can remember what I did in future :-)

---

So the first thing is to use `exiftool` to get all things related to the date:

```
exiftool image.jpg | grep -i date

File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:01:14 10:51:38+00:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:01:14 10:51:40+00:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:01:14 10:51:38+00:00
Modify Date                     : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
Date/Time Original              : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
Create Date                     : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
```

---

That looks useful, but internally `exiftool` uses **Perl** variables for the fields/tags, and I would like to get the variable names so I can compare them later, so I added `-s`:

```
exiftool -s image.jpg | grep -i date

FileModifyDate                  : 2021:01:14 10:51:38+00:00
FileAccessDate                  : 2021:01:14 10:51:40+00:00
FileInodeChangeDate             : 2021:01:14 10:51:38+00:00
ModifyDate                      : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
DateTimeOriginal                : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
CreateDate                      : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
```

---

Ok, I think you want `FileModifyDate` and `DateTimeOriginal`, so let's check we can print them:

```
exiftool -p '$Filename, $FileModifyDate, $DateTimeOriginal'  image.jpg

image.jpg, 2021:01:14 10:51:38+00:00, 2013:03:09 08:59:50
```

Note you **MUST** use single quotes on macOS/Linux else the `bash` shell tries to expand the variable and it expands to nothing - unless you happen to have a `bash` variable called `DateTimeOriginal`. I guess you would have to use double quotes on Windows because it doesn't generally understand single quotes.

---

That's good, but you aren't interested in the hours, minutes and seconds, so we can change the way `exiftool` considers dates to only look at the year, month and day with `-d`:

```
exiftool -d %F -p '$Filename, $FileModifyDate, $DateTimeOriginal'  image.jpg 

image.jpg, 2021-01-14, 2013-03-09
```

---

Now we want to check whether they are the same (for all JPEG files) with an `if` statement and only print *"unhappy"* files:

```
exiftool -d %F -if '$FileModifyDate !~ $DateTimeOriginal' -p '$FileName' *.jpg

image.jpg
iphone.jpg
2 files failed condition
```

If you are vaguely uneasy with **Perl** string comparisons like that, you could do the tests and printing with `awk` like this:

```
exiftool -d %F -p '$Filename, $FileModifyDate, $DateTimeOriginal' *.jpg | awk -F, '$2 != $3{print $1}'
```

Note the above only executes a single `exiftool` process. I think you probably want to avoid running a whole new process for `exiftool` with every file, so do NOT do this:

```
find ... -iname "*.jpg" -exec exiftool ... {} \;
```

---

I think you can recurse into subdirectories with `-r` but I haven't tried that.

---

By the way, on **macOS** you can install `exiftool` most simply with **homebrew**:

```
brew install exiftool
```

**Keywords**: exiftool, creation date. modification date, EXIF date, matching, non-matching, photo, photos, prime.

Comment: You can use wildcards to limit the names of extracted tags.  For example, you could use `exiftool -s -*date* image.jpg` to just get tags with `date` in the name instead of piping through grep.  But when it comes to time related tags, you can use `exiftool -Time:All image.jpg` to list all timestamps.

Comment: @StarGeek Ok, thank you for your help - as I said, I don't know `exiftool` that well, so I am always happy to learn from the insights of more experienced folk :-)

Comment: Any idea how to make https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455818/how-to-rsync-photos-from-a-specific-date-forward-namely-from-the-date-on-wh work?