# How to know what applications are available for the -a flag for the open command on mac command line

Tags: shell, file, command-line, zsh

I know that if I'm using the mac command line, I can open a file with the command

```
open file
```

Furthermore, if I know the name of the application with which I want to open the file, I should be able to open it with

```
open -a "Application" file
```

However, I can't figure out how to know what names I have available for "Applications," or how I might be able to add different applications to those that I can call in this way. Any pointers towards the right direction (or even what I could have done to figure this out on my own) would be so appreciated!

Comment: Please consider accepting (with the ✅) and upvoting the excellent answer provided for you by @WeihangJian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1

1. Click the  Apple icon at the top-left corner on your screen.
2. Click "About This Mac"
3. Click "System Report"
4. Navigate to "Software/Applications"

[image]

## Method 2

Use this method if your prefer CLI over GUI.

```sh
system_profiler -json SPApplicationsDataType | jq -r '.SPApplicationsDataType[] | ._name'
```

## Method 3

This is slow but it works.

```sh
find / -name *.app
```

Comment: Method 2 works very well indeed - thank you for sharing!

Comment: BTW, you can also see a list of installed applications with their names by looking at the launchpad, however, some of the applications do not appear there. For example 'about this mac' does not appear at the launchpad, though you can launch it using an open command

Answer (score 1):

I have often wondered myself and hope this crude method doesn't stop anyone who knows the actual answer from responding. Please don't rush to accept this work-around else folk will lose interest in sharing the proper answer.

I have two crude, clumsy methods...

**Method 1**: I can look for all things called `xxx.app` whilst discarding errors, like this:

```
find / -name "*.app" 2> /dev/null
```

**Method 2**: I get a list of all running processes and save it in a file, then I start the app I am looking for by double-clicking it, or from Spotlight, then I get a new list of what's running and compare to see what's new:

```
ps -aef > /tmp/a
# Launch app
ps -aef > /tmp/b
opendiff /tmp/{a,b}
```

---

There's also a `bundleId` that you can pass to `open`, and you can use `mdls` command on an app to get its `bundleId` - try it on **Pages** with:

```
mdls /Applications/Pages.app
```

So you can presumably use `mdfind` somehow to get bundleIds of everything that might be an app. Example of `mdfind` [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45900228/2836621)

The following gets a list of all things that Apple thinks might be application bundles:

```
mdfind "kMDItemContentType == 'com.apple.application-bundle'"
```